# Symfony 3: How to check LDAP inside Authenticator checkCredentials

Tags: symfony, authentication, ldap, symfony-3.3

I need to authenticate a user against an LDAP server with custom logic.

I'm implementing a custom authentication system in *Symfony 3.3*, and built a custom authenticator named **LoginFormAuthenticator** that extends **AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator**, as per:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

I need to check the username against a User entity in the database, then, depending on the type of user, either auth against a bcrypt password stored in the database, or against an external LDAP server.

Inside of the *checkCredentials* method, I can validate the password stored in the database successfully with:

```
    class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator {
     ...

            public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
            {
               ...

               // check password if the user is database user
               if ($user->getApp() == 'DB') {
                 if ($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
                      return true;
                 }
               }

               // check LDAP server if LDAP user
               if ($this->getApp() == 'LDAP') {
                if ($this->unknownLdapService->check($user, $password)
                {
                      return true;
                }
               ...
```

I'm not clear on the correct way to check the username and password against the LDAP server with native symfony functionality.

If I change my config to use form_login_ldap (and not my new authenticator), it does in fact successfully auth against LDAP, although where it makes the call is obfuscated to me.

What service or class I should be using to query LDAP in place of **unknownLdapService** above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I ended up using here was that I first injected the existing Symfony ldap service into the constructor of my method.  The ldap service is configured in **services.yml** the same way the Symfony docs configure it for the **form_login_ldap** provider.

```
/**
 * LoginFormAuthenticator constructor.
 * @param FormFactoryInterface $formFactory
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param RouterInterface $router
 * @param SecureUserPasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder
 * @param Ldap $ldap
 */
public function __construct(..., Ldap $ldap, ... )
{
    ...
    $this->ldap = $ldap;
}
```

Then inside of my checkCredentials method, I called the ldap bind method:

```
 public function checkCredentials($credentials, $userInterface $user)
    ...
    $password = $credentials['_password']; 
    $login_format = 'DOMAIN\%s';  // this is the expected format in my case
    $login_username = sprintf($login_format, $user);
    ...
    try {
        // try to bind with the username and provided password
        $this->ldap->bind($login_username, $password);
    } catch (\Symfony\Component\Ldap\Exception\ConnectionException $e) {
        //return false;
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('The submitted LDAP password is invalid.');
    };
        return true;
    };
```

This works, and if the ldap auth fails, it throws the appropriate exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can could use your own LDAP service: you just need to call ldap_bind. (it can allows you to do more ldap checks or to mock it aswell)

You could alose use the Symfony provider: vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/LdapBindAuthenticationProvider.php

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider;

class LdapBindAuthenticationProvider extends UserAuthenticationProvider
{
    private $userProvider;
    private $ldap;
    private $dnString;

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, UserCheckerInterface $userChecker, $providerKey, LdapClientInterface $ldap, $dnString = '{username}', $hideUserNotFoundExceptions = true)
    {
        parent::__construct($userChecker, $providerKey, $hideUserNotFoundExceptions);

        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
        $this->ldap = $ldap;
        $this->dnString = $dnString;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function retrieveUser($username, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
    {
        if ('NONE_PROVIDED' === $username) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Username can not be null');
        }

        return $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function checkAuthentication(UserInterface $user, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
    {
        $username = $token->getUsername();
        $password = $token->getCredentials();

        if ('' === $password) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password must not be empty.');
        }

        try {
            $username = $this->ldap->escape($username, '', LDAP_ESCAPE_DN);
            $dn = str_replace('{username}', $username, $this->dnString);

            $this->ldap->bind($dn, $password);
        } catch (ConnectionException $e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password is invalid.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did see that LdapBindAuthenticationProvider exists, but how would you call checkAuthentication since it's a protected method?

Comment: It seems you can use ''UserAuthenticationProvider" which has public methods `authenticate`. It supports `UsernamePasswordToken`. I never used it personally